# Highstock with php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

i want to make chart with mysql database. I have two columns - timestamp and temperature. This is the timestamp format - 2015-06-11 22:45:59 and the temperature is integer. Im not sure that my conversion of timestamp to javascript time is correct i have or maybe i have other mistake. this is my code:

data.php

```
<?
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','root');
define('DBPASS','...');
define('DBNAME','diplomna2');

try {

    //create PDO connection 
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=3306;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    exit;
}
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM temperature');

$res=array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $row['timestamp'] = strtotime($row['timestamp']);
   $row['timestamp'] *=1000;

    echo $res="[".$row['timestamp'] . ',' . $row['temperature'] ."]";

}
?>
```

this is the output:

```
[1434051959000,25][1434051969000,26][1434051979000,26][1434051990000,28][1434052000000,27][1434052024000,25][1434052034000,24][1434052044000,23]
```

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $.getJSON('data.php', function(data) {

                // Create the chart
                $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


                    rangeSelector : {
                        inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 480,
                        selected : 1
                    },

                    title : {
                        text : 'Temperature'
                    },

                    series : [{
                        name : 'temperature',
                        data : data,
                        type : 'areaspline',
                        threshold : null,
                        tooltip : {
                            valueDecimals : 2
                        },
                        fillColor : {
                            linearGradient : {
                                x1: 0,
                                y1: 0,
                                x2: 0,
                                y2: 1
                            },
                            stops : [
                                [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                                [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                            ]
                        }
                    }]
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way to make JavaScript understand your PHP array is `json_encode()`

Change your code block near `while` to

```
$res = [];

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $res[] = [ strtotime($row['timestamp'])*1000, $row['temperature'] ];
}

echo json_encode($res);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I changed the code  but it  doesn't work again.

Comment: what error are you getting, check in your browser console.

Comment: > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEvent' of undefined
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fireEvent' of undefined
> test_temperature.php:25 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: omg .. :D ok. i include it, but there is a list of errors .When I open them there are the following errors:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEvent' of undefined(anonymous function) @ highstock.js:308(anonymous function) @ highstock.js:311(anonymous function) @ highstock.js:413

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fireEvent' of undefined(anonymous function) @ exporting.js:9(anonymous function) @ exporting.js:23

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier.

I'll check the mistakes one by one and see where is the problem. Thanks for help :)

Comment: Include jQuery **before** Highstock ;)

Comment: everything is ok. i add jquery and change values of temperature to be int :)